# Pandas 'min' aggregate, but how to set 'min'+1?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to aggregate my pandas dataframe with minimum and also minimum+1. Let me explain.
Suppose I have a dataframe:

```
  distance  vertex  type
0   8       104     A
1   1       114     A
2   1       103     B
3   2       102     A
4   3       18      A
5   3       108     B
```

I get the minimum distance with groupby on Type as follows:

```
mask = df['distance'].isin(df.groupby(['type'])['distance'].agg('min').values)
df[mask]
```

This gives me minimum distance for each Type.

```
  distance  vertex  type
1   1       114     A
2   1       103     B
```

**My question:** How do I get rows that are satisfying the following formula:

*distance = minimum(distance) + 1*

This is what I'm trying to get.

```
  distance  vertex  type
1   1       114     A
2   1       103     B
3   2       102     A
```

Comment: What you want is unclear, with the groupby you get the min per group, but then pool all minima together to filter your DataFrame. Is this wanted?

Comment: Also, please update your output, the vertex values do not match those in the input ;)

Comment: I actually figured it out. But for the sake of learning..
I want to groupby and aggregate not only on the minimum but also minimum+1

Comment: Check if my answer below solves your issue ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact logic is unclear, but assuming you want to filter **per group** to keep the values equal to the minimum or minimum +1, use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
mask = df['distance'].le(df.groupby(['type'])['distance'].transform('min').add(1))

out = df[mask]
```

Output:

```
   distance  vertex type
1         1     114    A
2         1     103    B
3         2     102    A
```

Comment: works perfectly and is much cleaner than my stupid solution :) I should learn the transform and le functions..

Answer (score 0):

This is what I wrote at first, but its wrong and here just as a "Dead code" for people to see and be aware :). See comments why its wrong..

```
mask = df['distance'].isin([df.groupby(['Type'])['distance'].agg('min').values[0], df.groupby(['Type'])['distance'].agg('min').values[0]+1])
```

Comment: But do you really want this logic? Here this pools all minima together and filters independently of the groups. For instance if you have a group A with minimum 9, then if a Group B with minimum 1 has values of 9 and 10, they will be selected. Do you want this?

Comment: I didnt get that, if Group A has minimum 9 and other values are 7, 6, 4, 1 and Group B has minimum 4 and other values are 3, 2, 0. Then I want A with 9 only and B with 4 and 3. Does that make it clear?

Comment: Yes, but this is not what your code would do, if would mix the groups together in the `isin` step.

Comment: oh yes I see what your saying now...thanks for following up on this <3